# IE 8 Built in Export to Excel feature from an ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Using IE 8 there's an option to "Export to Excel" when you right click on a grid view.

Within ASP.NET I'm filtering on varions columns and returning a smaller view of the data.

If right click and "Export to Excel" I get the unfiltered results, not the results displayed on my web page!

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong / how to resolve.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the database is re-queried on the export...